Apply a decorator over a method already decorated with @property in Python
Why the code bellow doesn't work when the @property decorator
is applied on the method already decorated with @property? (I am using Python 3.10.)
# Define a decorator
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Decorator applied")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

# Apply the decorator over the method
class MyClass:
    @my_decorator
    @property
    def x(self):
        return 42

# Test the decorated method
obj = MyClass()
print(obj.x)  # should output "Decorator applied" followed by "42"

But the print gives:
<bound method my_decorator.<locals>.wrapper of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7e0b7943ebf0>>
This is already a minimal example compared with my real scenario where my decorator is much more complex and also I have multiple decorators.

Is there a reason why you don't use wraps anymore ? Without it, the docs of your function will be always clobbered and set to None. For me it works as expected with the @wraps(func) before the wrapper function.

The property decorator transforms a function into a special property object. It wouldn't work to then pass that property object to another decorator that expects a function. You should change the order of decorators.

Also, if you expect obj.x to return 42 then obj.x.__doc__ will be the docstring for int, not for the decorated function.

@interjay the docs stuf was a mistake but  about the property decorator weirdly it worked changing the order...

@baskettaz did you set the property decorator too?

I don't believe your code worked on Python 3.8. Anyway, you can create a new property like this example. If you edit your question for correctness, I'll answer it with an explanation.

@interjay, FYI, you can wrap a property using a decorator as in the snippet, linked on the above comment.

@imbr, all the comments were to the point. When you're using the @property, you're creating special descriptor, which isn't method anymore. The changing of the order worked, because you're decorating the function, before the transformation to property.

@relent95 you are right. I was not using a decorator.

@relent95 nice.. I will take a look on your code to undersand better `property class thanks a lot

@baskettaz you right changing the order works, altough the inner behaviour I will research more on

The @property decorator is based on the descriptor protocol. The Python interpreter handles an attribute lookup in a special way, when a class attribute of the same name is defined and it provides a __get__ method. See the reference for details.
Once you understand the descriptor protocol, you can understand how the @property decorator works, by looking at the implementation of it. The actual implementation is in C, but the reference and the source contains pure Python equivalents, here some of it.
class property(object):

    def __init__(self, fget=None, ...):
        ...
        self.__get = fget
        ...

    def __get__(self, inst, type=None):
        ...
        return self.__get(inst)

The following is a simple example of the @property decorator.
class X:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.a * 10

x = X(1)
print(x.b) # This will output 10.

The definition of the property b is equivalent to the following. (It's a simple application of the general decorator syntax.)
    def get_b(self):
        return self.a * 10
    b = property(get_b)

When the Python interpreter handles the attribute lookup x.b, it identifies there exists a class attribute b in the X and the attribute provides the __get__ method. So, the interpreter calls the __get__method following the descriptor protocol. Inside the __get__ method, the interpreter calls the get_b method which was the argument of the property call.
Once you understand the implementation of the @property, you can wrap a property using a decorator by defining a new property, as in the following example.
def decorator_on_prop(prop):
    def new_fget(self):
        return prop.fget(self) + 1
    return property(new_fget)

class X:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @decorator_on_prop
    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.a * 10

x = X(1)
print(x.b) # This will output 11.

